# Prevent encrypted partition from running on other PC

Tags: hardware, encryption, disk-encryption

**Concise question**:  Is it possible to somehow bind partition encryption to hardware so it is impossible(very hard) to copy system to another PC and run there?

**Full story**: We have a small embedded PC with Linux running inside a device, we develop. As the device turns on, embedded PC just runs, showing data to users until power-off.

Software on this PC is our commercial competitive advantage so we would like to prevent access to it as much as possible (see P.S.).

So the idea is to encrypt the system flash or at least a part of it. But then it is possible just to copy the entire flash. Then, the next idea is to bind the encryption to hardware. But how?

P.S. I know that everything is a subject for reverse engineering, but it is not the reason to leave reverse engineering of your product flat and unchallenging.

P.P.S I'm not paranoid about copying. Unfortunately, we know competitors who will try to steal the technology by names =)

Comment: Just to play devil's advocate.  What is going to happen when this PC dies?  I think a better choice would be to use a very strong encryption with a key file.  Never store the key file and the data in the same place.  This would still allow disaster recovery.

Comment: When the PC dies, we replace it with new same kind PC (with new encrypted flash). PC doesn't have any data to mourn. It receives information from the device, aggregates it and shows to user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can bind encrypted data to a specific device using a [Trusted Platform Module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Platform_Module) (TPM). These have become quite common in *x86* laptops over the last few years, and can be installed in many servers too.

Using a TPM, you can generate an encryption key which only exists in the module, and encrypt data using that; if you generate a key which can't be backed up, then you can be sure that the data can only be encrypted with the corresponding TPM. Copying the raw storage device is useless then. On Linux you could use [TrouSerS](http://trousers.sourceforge.net/) to manage this.

On ARM platforms you could do something similar with a key stored using [TrustZone](http://www.arm.com/products/processors/technologies/trustzone/index.php), but I don't know the details.

Comment: I believe TrustZone is a software separation technology, not an encryption module.

Comment: As I understand it, there is a secure element which can be used to store keys, and trusted encryption modules can then be used to provide encryption and decryption without the rest of the system being able to access any of it.

Comment: OK, you are right.

Answer (score 2):

Use a microprocessor that has built in flash that can not be read externally.  Many modern ARM chips have such capability.  In that flash you put your code and encryption keys needed to access any external storage.

Comment: That would be the best solution. Unfortunately there is no such chip in the current hardware revision. Cut JTAG legs?))) But that is not an option.  Thought we could use something else. Is there processor serial number or something available?

Comment: If you use the processor serial number as a passphrase or use it to derive a passphrase, then it's probably no different from using a good passphrase, IMO. It might even be worse if attackers manage to retrieve your processor serial number, which makes it kind of akin to putting a post-it with the password in your computer.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot really rely on cryptographic secrets in this case, because your embedded PC will need to know those secrets to function, and so the attacker will potentially know them as well.

One solution would be to find or make a secret which is unreadable from outside (in a similar way as @psusi suggested). It's hard to suggest something without knowing what kind of hardware you have exactly. Maybe a processor serial number is a good option, although I wonder if you can read it via JTAG as well.

Another way to solve this is obfuscation. Instead of a code which starts with a decryption procedure (and makes it obvious where the secret is coming from) you should develop a code which uses the secret several times in random parts of the program. For example, instead of hardcoding a buffer size somewhere you could use the n-th digit of your processor's serial number multiplied by 1000. This will make the code crash on a different hardware configuration, and it will require lots of debugging before the adversary finds out which secret is used and how.

If you need a more detailed answer you need to provide details as well. What is the threat model (illegal copying to similar hardware, disassembly of your proprietary algorithms, something else)? What is your hardware? What are the relevant constraints (you said you cannot cut off JTAG pins, why?)

Answer (score 1):

I have used an internal GPG secure card for a similar purpose on a dedicated system that is up 24*7, with software that:

1. decrypts the protected parts of the software before they get loaded into memory
2. that software and the loaded protected software check for snooping on memory (i.e. process on the system not condoned by us) as well as for unsigned modifications to the software
3. If the system is rebooted, our website is checked with data uniquely coming from the card and data sent back that allows further decryption (as long as the system is up).
4. In case the software decides an attempt is being made to reverse engineer it, it writes an encrypted log (which we can review) and blocks the secure card from functioning.

When you replace the normal readable part of the software, it is still very unlikely you get access to the encrypted part. 
This is not foolproof and it requires an internet connection at boot time, but saves against the system, when stolen, being able to boot and reveal decrypted software (unless it is stolen without removing the power).

Answer (score 1):

My server produces its encryption key based on hardware data such as CPU type, available memory, network MAC address, ... that enables the machine to reboot itself unsupervised, and if you took out the disk and put it into another server, it could not decrypt itself.

But it's a moot point in an embedded system, or indeed anywhere you have root access, since you can always just query the key using `dmsetup table --showkeys`.

So it seems to me that your best bet would be to put encryption in hardware.

And the second best bet, to patch your kernel somehow so the above `dmsetup` command won't be able to query the encryption keys used, and maybe bake the key generation into the kernel itself, so it can't be grabbed from Initramfs either.

It can still be grabbed from a memory dump but that's still the best you can do...

Of course it's all a moot point if the running system sees all data unencrypted and someone gains access and can just copy that unencrypted view.